# In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows - indirect formula error in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Hy Guys, 
i'm triyng to merge two different Tab of the same Google SpreadSheet.

I'm using this formula in the first cell

```
={indirect(dynamicRange1);indirect(dynamicRange2)}
```

where dynamicRange 1 and 2 are:

- FirstSheet!2:2606
- SecondSheet!2:6598

But shomething does not work fine.

"In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows"

If i use just one dynamicRance everything works fine, both something goes wrong.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Number of columns in both sheets must be the same:

Try

```
={Sheet1!A2:D10;Sheet2!A2:D10}
```

Comment: I've deleted blank (and useless) columns, so it works fine, also with dynamicRange

Answer (score 6):

This error is generated when the number of columns in two array is not the same:

> In `ARRAY_LITERAL`, an array literal was missing values for one or more rows

You need same number of columns in all arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You need same number of columns in all arrays. You should keep the same number of columns in all imported sheets, **even if you have empty columns**. Deleting empty column in at least one sheet will cause an error.