# Google sheets import from multiple sheets giving error

Tags: google-sheets

I have created a master sheet which imports the data for the other sheets which are representing the dates of the month. In the sheet the master sheet cell A2 has the formula to import from the other sheets which the google sheet

Google [Spread Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12SKBgX_Tjpg4D9ObkOs7oC61sMaaNJa911UNk3gBaA8/edit?usp=sharing).

The issue I am facing is that if in the formula I change the sheet 10 range from A2:CH to A2:CO it gives an error

> Error
>   In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

I am not being able to find the problem as this is not a permissions issue and neither does sheet 10 have any data in this case.

full code is below:

```
=UNIQUE(query({'1'!A2:CO;'2'!A2:CO;'3'!A2:CO;'4'!A2:CO;'5'!A2:CO;'6'!A2:CO;'7'!A2:CO;'8'!A2:CO;'9'!A2:CO;'10'!A2:CO;'11'!A2:CO;'12'!A2:CO;'13'!A2:CO;'14'!A2:CO;'15'!A2:CO;'16'!A2:CO;'17'!A2:CO;'18'!A2:CO;'19'!A2:CO;'20'!A2:CO;'21'!A2:CO;'22'!A2:CO;'23'!A2:CO;'24'!A2:CO;'25'!A2:CO;'26'!A2:CO;'27'!A1:CO;'28'!A2:CO;'29'!A2:CO;'30'!A2:CO;'31'!A2:CO},"select * where Col1 is not null"))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In ARRAY\_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows - indirect formula error in google spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678262/in-array-literal-an-array-literal-was-missing-values-for-one-or-more-rows-ind)

Comment: hi while i was looking for the specific issue causing the sheet to get the error this link is the root of the issue