# Removing header row in Google sheets query pivot

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, row, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

While removing the header row in a Google sheets query function seems straightforward, I don't see any suggestions on removing the header row when the query involves a pivot. For reference, I am giving a link with viewing rights to a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o_CHpfYmEQ4evz6PBH_N8ufBZPL3tN-KSyJOvbnSuCA/edit?usp=sharing) which replicates the structure of the one I am working with.

The query is in cell C4 of the tab "Query sheet" and reads as follows:

```
= QUERY('Class hours'!A2:C11,"select sum(C) WHERE A='" & A5 & "' group by A pivot B")
```

The aim is to remove the row headers in cells C4:E4 in this sheet so that this function can be copied down column C to include all names in Column A with corresponding Sum (C) in the rows. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
=QUERY(QUERY('Class hours'!A2:C11,
 "select sum(C) 
  where A = '"&A5&"' 
  group by A 
  pivot B"), 
 "offset 1", 0)
```

or even this in your case:

```
=INDEX(QUERY('Class hours'!A2:C11,
 "select sum(C) 
  where A = '"&A5&"' 
  group by A 
  pivot B"), 2)
```