# Merging Multiple Google Workbooks using Importrange

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am attempting to merge several workbooks into one using the QUERY & IMPORTRANGE functions. I can do it for one url but not for two or more.

Below is the code I was working with.

`=(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1eektUNSkM1buTolWF6o6gU5H6aJU5kqoUhgAPgipnZk", "1.1_Goal_Plan!A1:V70"); IMPORTRANGE("12b8HAacbSEN7hQMlnPU8froVs1ACWf_7782DMYvtbLA", "1.1_Goal_Plan!A1:V70")}, "where Col1 is not null",0))`

It returns the below error.

**In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.**

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that A1:V70 exist in both sheets? That error message can mean that the array sizes that you are attempting to join are not compatible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678262/in-array-literal-an-array-literal-was-missing-values-for-one-or-more-rows-ind

Comment: Ahhh, correct. I had to add more rows so that the data flowed properly. Thanks