# I am unable to stack the following filter formulas

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is the formula I am using, I keep getting

> In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

can someone help me fix the syntax please?

```
={FILTER({Lookup!AM3:AM, Lookup!AP3:AP,Lookup!AR3:AR,Lookup!M3:M,Lookup!U3:U,Lookup!V3:V,Lookup!W3:W,Lookup!X3:X,Lookup!Y3:Y,Lookup!Z3:Z,Lookup!AT3:AT}, Lookup!H3:H = "US/CAN - NYC Metro",Lookup!Z3:Z > A1);
  FILTER({Lookup!AM3:AM, Lookup!AP3:AP,Lookup!AR3:AR,Lookup!M3:M,Lookup!U3:U,Lookup!V3:V,Lookup!W3:W,Lookup!X3:X,Lookup!Y3:Y,Lookup!Z3:Z,Lookup!AT3:AT}, Lookup!H3:H = "US/CAN - Northeast",Lookup!Z3:Z > A1)}
```

Comment: I didn't find any issues with your actual formula, and It is hard to figure out what is fully going on here without the sheet, but I can give you a few checks you can do and places to look that may help. `1.  You can only stack results of exactly the same number of columns.` `2. https://www.reddit.com/r/googlesheets/comments/scujb6/comment/hu985vp/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3` `3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678262/in-array-literal-an-array-literal-was-missing-values-for-one-or-more-rows-ind`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER({Lookup!AM3:AM, Lookup!AP3:AP, Lookup!AR3:AR, Lookup!M3:M, Lookup!U3:U, Lookup!V3:V, Lookup!W3:W, Lookup!X3:X, Lookup!Y3:Y, Lookup!Z3:Z, Lookup!AT3:AT}, 
 REGEXMATCH(Lookup!H3:H, "US/CAN - NYC Metro|US/CAN - Northeast"), Lookup!Z3:Z > A1)
```