# Array_Literal Issue in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am not able to figure why the formaula is giving out Array_Literal error code when I am doing everything right.

Formula:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/dfnk", "Dotpe Import!A2:C15000");
FILTER("RISTA Import!A2:C2500", "RISTA Import!E2:E2500" = 1)}
```

Error Code:

```
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.
```

I also, looked at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49678262/in-array-literal-an-array-literal-was-missing-values-for-one-or-more-rows-ind), and according to it, I have same column count in both arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try both the scenarios and see if it works out.

`={IMPORTRANGE("[SPREADSHEET ID]", "Dotpe Import!A2:C15000"); FILTER('RISTA Import'!A1:C2500,'RISTA Import'!E1:E2500 = 1)}`

-

`={IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("[SPREADSHEET ID]", "Dotpe Import!A2:C15000"),MAKEARRAY(1,3,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(1/0)))); IFERROR(FILTER('RISTA Import'!A1:C2500,'RISTA Import'!E1:E2500 = 1),MAKEARRAY(1,3,LAMBDA(r,c,IFERROR(1/0))))}`

Answer (score 0):

see (not): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767719/locale-differences-in-google-sheets-documentation-missing-pages

[image]

use:

```
={IFERROR(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/dfnk", "Dotpe Import!A2:C15000"), {"","",""});
  IFERROR(FILTER("RISTA Import!A2:C2500", "RISTA Import!E2:E2500" = 1), {"","",""})}
```